# How can i read the text from richTextbox and keep the format of the text?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

For example inside the richTextBox I have the text:

```
Hello world
Hello hi

Hi all
```

Now I want to read this text with this format including the empty line/s and then to write back to the same file the same text with or without changes like deleted text or added text.

For example, if I delete the all then the text to write back will be in this format:

```
Hello world
Hello hi

Hi
```

Just without the all
Or

```
Hello world
Hello hi

Hi all everyone
```

So now it will write the same text but with the everyone but will keep the format.

I tried this but this adding too many empty lines and spaces that was not before:

```
var lines = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n');
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, lines);
```

Then i tried:

```
var text = richTextBox1.Text;
File.WriteAllText(fileName, text);
```

This wrote to the file the same text with the changes but it didn't keep the format it wrote the text to the file as one line.

Comment: To save: `richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileName);`  To load: `richTextBox1.LoadFile(fileName);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to replace "\n" with "\r\n"

```
var text = richTextBox1.Text;
text = text.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
File.WriteAllText(fileName, text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a several options here, none of which involve splitting the text.

Note: All the code below is using a private variable that has the file path as a string:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const string filePath = @"f:\public\temp\temp.txt";
```

The first one is to simply save all the text (including the `\r\n` characters) using the `Text` property, along with `File.ReadAllText` and `File.WriteAllText`:

```
// Load text on Form Load
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
    }
}

// Save text on button click
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, richTextBox1.Text);
}
```

If you want to do it line by line, you can use `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.WriteAllLines` along with the `Lines` property of the `RichTextBox`:

```
// Load text on Form Load
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        richTextBox1.Lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    }
}

// Save text on button click
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, richTextBox1.Lines);
}
```

Finally, you could use the built-in `SaveFile` and `LoadFile` methods of the `RichTextBox` class. This method will write metadata to the file, so if you open it in notepad you will see some additional characters that include all kinds of format information. Because of this, I added a `try/catch` block around the call to `LoadFile`, since it will throw and exception if the file does not have the correct format, and I fall back to loading it with `ReadAllText`:

```
// Load text on Form Load
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        try
        {
            richTextBox1.LoadFile(filePath);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            // Fall back to plain text method if the 
            // file wasn't created by the RichTextbox
            richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
        }
    }
}

// Save text on button click
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextBox1.SaveFile(filePath);
}
```